# User level Security to dc.js graphs

Tags: dc.js

In need to help again. 
I have finally built few dashboards and now the request from user is to show restricted data based on users.
Is there a way to have user level security?
Appreciate your suggestions!!

Comment: This isn't really a dc.js question - in itself, dc.js has no security features. (And it's actually pretty easy to poke around and learn things about a dc.js dashboard using the debugger, once it's loaded.) You'd have to check authentication and authorization before the dashboard is loaded. Usually there is a server-side component to this.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Gordon!!